# How do I return the response from a cy.request through a function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, request, return, cypress

I am trying to pass the result of an API request using the following function:

```js
Add(someName) {
        cy.request ({
            method: 'POST',
            url: someURL,
            body: {
                name: someName
            }
        }).then(function(response){
            return response
        })
    }
```

When I try to call this function however, it does not give me the content of the response (it gives me Undefined). I thought this probably has something to do with either asynchronosity (if that is a word),or the scope of the object and therefore tried aliasing the response or defining an object outside of the function (then assigning the response to that object), without any luck.

Comment: I had a similar question here and got an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76690604/how-do-i-return-only-a-part-of-a-response-from-a-cy-request-through-a-function

Answer (score 8):

You just need a `return` on the `cy.request()` call.

```js
Add(someName) {
  return cy.request ({...})
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.body      // maps the response to it's body
    })                         // so return value of function is response.body 
}
```

The return value type is a Chainer (the same type as all Cypress commands) so you ***must*** use a `.then()` on it

```
myPO.Add('myName').then(body => ...
```

---

**You don't need `.then()` after `cy.request()`**

If you want the full response,

```js
Add(someName) {
  return cy.request ({...})    // don't need a .then() after this 
                              // to return full response
}
```

---

**How to await the result**

If you want to await the result, use a `Cypress.Promise` as shown [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/promise#Waiting-for-Promises)

```js
Add(someName) {
  return new Cypress.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    cy.request ({...})
      .then(response => resolve(response))
  })
}
```

Awaiting

```js
const response = await myPO.Add('myName')
```

Comment: you saved my entire life

Comment: I have a related question here and hoping you could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76690604/how-do-i-return-only-a-part-of-a-response-from-a-cy-request-through-a-function

Answer (score 2):

You should try returning something in your function:

```
Add(someName)
{
    return cy.request ({
        method: 'POST',
        url: someURL,
        body: {
            name: someName
        }
    }).then(function(response){
        return response
    })
}
```

And then get the value returned:

```
Add('val').then((data) => {console.log(data)})
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using cy.wrap!

In the below example you can do anything before the return:

```
export const add = (someName) => {
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: someURL,
    body: {
        name: someName
    }
}).then((resp) => {
    cy.wrap(resp)
      .as('requestResp')
  })

   // Here you can do anything

  return cy.get('@requestResp')
}
```

Comment: Why so complicated? Just return the `cy.request()` as shown above.

Comment: Using this way, you can add cypress commands between the `cy.request` and the `return` e.g. you can add `cy.wait`

Comment: Wrapping in a promise is a better way to wait, rather than a hard-coded time period. If you add to much other (unspecified) stuff, you are introducing side effects which is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try the following:
Return the response from this function,

```
function getApiResponse(): Cypress.ObjectLike {

     return cy.request ({
        method: 'POST',
        url: someURL,
        body: {
            name: someName
        }
    })
}
```

And then call it in the required places:

```
getApiResponse().then(response => {
  cy.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Copy of answer above.