# Can't seem to get value from cy.request but I can console.log the value

Tags: node.js, promise, cypress, request-promise

I am trying to call an endpoint using cypress and get a value out form the JSON body. I am able to `console.log(response.body.data.invitationCode)` out fine but can't seem to assign that value to a variable (I want to pass that value to subsequent requests). I've tried using [promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68936669/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-a-cy-request-through-a-function) but I still can't get the value.

Here is my code:

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />
const faker = require('faker');

// We can change this to an ENV variable if we want to run this in different environments
const baseURL = 'https://<my url>/';

const user = {
  createUser: async function () {
    let code;
    await user.waitListEndpointCall().then((response) => {
      {
        //console.log(response.body.data.invitationCode) works like a charm
        code = response.body.data.invitationCode;
      }
    });
    console.log(code); //doesn't work
  },

  /**
   * Function calls the '/api/v1/public/waitList/post' and returns an invitation code
   */
  waitListEndpointCall: function () {
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: `${baseURL}/api/v1/public/waitList/post`,
      body: {
        email: `dmtest-${faker.random.number(1000001)}@gmail.com`,
      },
    };

    return cy.request(options);

    // return new Cypress.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //   cy.request(options).then((response) => resolve(response));
    // });
  },
};

module.exports = {
  user,
};
```

`console.log(code)` gives me `undefined` in cypress.

I've even wrapped my `cy.request` in a promise like so:

```
waitListEndpointCall: function(){
const options: {
...
}   
return new Cypress.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          cy.request(options).then((response) => resolve(response));
        });
}
```

calling it like via:

```
let res = await user.waitListEndpointCall();
console.log(res.body);
```

and I still get `undefined`

Comment: `waitListEndpointCall` is not an async function so its content is executed synchronously even if you try to await it.

Comment: @Dez sorry, I was just playing around with awaits. I removed the `await` it and I still get `undefinded`. Trying to get a trivial solution for this rather than using callbacks after callbacks to pass JSON values to other requests.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't really `await` a Cypress command.

Cypress runs commands in a queue, and return values are wrapped in a `Chainable` to make the queue work.

The options you have are

- return the Chainable and use it's `.then()` method to unwrap the value

  ```js
  waitListEndpointCall: function () {
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: `${baseURL}/api/v1/public/waitList/post`,
      body: {
        email: `dmtest-${faker.random.number(1000001)}@gmail.com`,
      },
    };
    return cy.request(options)
  })
  ...
  user.waitListEndpointCall().then(response => ...
  ```
- use a `fetch()` instead

  ```js
  waitListEndpointCall: function () {
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: `${baseURL}/api/v1/public/waitList/post`,
      body: {
        email: `dmtest-${faker.random.number(1000001)}@gmail.com`,
      },
    };
    return fetch(options)
  }
  ...
  let res = await user.waitListEndpointCall()
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a problem with your Promise strategy. If I run it with a minimal reproducible example, it passes.

```js
const user = {
  waitListEndpointCall: function () {
    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
    }
    return new Cypress.Promise((resolve) => {
      cy.request(options).then((response) => resolve(response));
    })
  }
}

it('tests promise-wrapped return value', async () => {
  const res = await user.waitListEndpointCall()
  expect(res).to.have.property('body')                    // passes
})
```