# How do I return only a part of a response from a cy.request through a function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

This is a follow up to a question someone else had asked here [How do I return the response from a cy.request through a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68936669/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-a-cy-request-through-a-function)

I want to make a function which calls an api, processes the response and returns only a portion of the response. I have the below code which codes not work. I get the compiler error - a function whose type is neither undefined, void or null should return a value. How do I make this work?

```
Add(someName) : ItemClass {
    cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: someURL,
        body: {
            name: someName
        }
    }).then(function(response) {
       let result = response.body.find((item) => {return item.id === 123})
       return result; // result is of type ItemClass
    })
}
```

Comment: And it must return something, that promise, for example.

Comment: @Unmitigated - can you show me a code example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The prior linked question shows you need the `return cy.request(...)` syntax, but since you are also using Typescript you also need to alter the return type.

`cy.request()` yields a generic `Chainable` type, so the return type might be

```js
Add(someName) : Chainable<ItemClass> {
  return cy.request({
    ...
```

But the response is a standard javascript Response type and `item` looks like an `object`, so as it stands the return type is

```js
Add(someName) : Chainable<Object> {
  return cy.request({
    ...
```

If you have a class for `ItemClass`, and want to return an instance of `ItemClass`, you will need to instantiate it into the `.then()` callback.

---

**Type reference**

The `request` command type definition is given [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/1fcdc878b601d1eee870e30ee012993443d61742/cli/types/cypress.d.ts#L1865)

> ```js
> request<T = any>(url: string, body?: RequestBody): Chainable<Response<T>>
> ```